# Passing data via an Angular 2 service

Tags: angular2-services

I'm struggling to pass data from an Angular service to a component. I start with a simple model class (./cet.model)

```
export class CetModel {
constructor(
    public waferDiameter: number = 10
    ) {}
}
```

Then define an angular service (./cet.service);

```
import { CetModel } from './cet.model';

export class CetService {
    private cet: CetModel;

    getCet() {
    return this.cet;
    }      
}
```

And the associated angular component;

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { CetService } from './cet.service';
import { CetModel } from './cet.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'cet-input',
    templateUrl: './cet-input.component.html',
    providers: [ CetService ]
})

export class CetInputComponent {
   constructor(public cetService: CetService){}
   cet: CetModel = this.cetService.getCet();
   waferDiameter = this.cet.waferDiameter
}
```

The code builds without errors, but when I try to display the variable 'waferDiameter' in the component's template I receive the error;

"Cannot read property 'waferDiameter' of undefined".

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I believe that you are lacking the "this" word in front of waferDiameter or in other words try out this.waferDiameter = this.cet.waferDiameter, that is of course correct if your waferDiameter is a declared filed within the component class

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the feedback. If I edit the angular component code to 'this.waferDiameter = this.cet.waferDiameter' then I get the following Linter and Build error - "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code in **cet.service** as follows :

```
import { CetModel } from './cet.model';

    export class CetService {
        private cet = new CetModel();

        getCet() {
        return this.cet;
        }      
    }
```

You have not created the model object. That's why `this.cet`returns undefined and you get `waferDiameter` undefined.

Comment: I tried the edit you suggest. I get linter and build error - "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target."

Comment: My Mistake - your solution does work - the last error was caused by an unrelated bug. Thanks again.